# In the Tchernobyl nuclear plant of the 1986 accident, were there a secondary circuit, or were there only a primary circuit?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

In a typical modern nuclear plant, there are :

- a primary circuit, which allows to transfert the heat of the fission (transfered to the water) to a secondary circuit.
- a secondary circuit, which transforms the liquid form of the fluid into steam, used afterwards to create electricity.
- a tertiary circuit, which transforms back the steam in liquid form.

In the Tchernobyl nuclear plant of the 1986 accident, were there a secondary circuit, or were there only a primary circuit ?

If there were no secondary circuit : what is the advantage/purpose of the existence of a *secondary* circuit in a *modern* nuclear plant ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many different reactors systems have been developped .

Mainly , six types are used to-day : Magnox , AGR , PWR , BWR , CANDU and RBMK .

So , they are different : it an obvious fact  !
RBMK - like Tchernobyl - is an " old system " derived from military reactors to produce plutonium used in the  West as in the  East .

Yes , primary light water and steam drive directly a turbine in RBMK system .
A secondary circuit is a supplementary safety device : secondary water has no physical contact with primary water ( if exchangers are in perfect condition ...).

And yes , RBMK is believed in the West to be inherently  less safe than a modern PWR like EPR .

Comment: Thank you for your help